# remove undefined label in the upper part of a chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using Chart.js library in my project and I have one issue that I could't solve.
[This label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSMf1.png) that describes what the data shown is about, is one info that I don't actually need in my project. How can I remove it completely?
In another chart I need to place it in the right side of the chart, but I can't manage it. How can I solve these two problems that I have?
At the moment my code looks like this:

```
type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: data.map(x => moment(x.date).format("MMM Do")),
        datasets: [{
            data: data.map(x => x.premium),
            backgroundColor: '#ffec87',
            borderColor: "#ffec87",
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderStyle: 'dotted'
        }]
    },
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Since its part of the `legend` you will need to configure it in the options.

Don't show at all example:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'orange'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Show it on the right side example:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'orange'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        position: 'right'
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Dont show undefined labels:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      },
      {
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'orange'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        labels: {
          filter: (legendItem, data) => (typeof legendItem.text !== 'undefined')
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

For more information you can read the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/configuration/legend.html) about it

Answer (score -2):

I agree with LeeLenalee answer but I think you need this for aligning:

```
plugins: {
    legend: {
      align: 'end',
    }
  },
```